# Does C# resolve dependencies among static data members automatically?

Tags: c#, static, data-members

If one static data member depends on another static data member, does C#/.NET guarantee the depended static member is initialized before the dependent member?

For example, we have one class like:

```
class Foo
{
    public static string a = "abc";

    public static string b = Foo.a + "def";
}
```

When **Foo.b** is accessed, is it always "abcdef" or can be "def"?

If this is not guaranteed, is there any better way to make sure depended member initialized first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like said before, static field initialization is deterministic and goes according to the textual declaration ordering.

Take this, for example:

```
class Foo
{
    public static string b = a + "def";
    public static string a = "abc";
}
```

Foo.b will always result in "def".

For that matter, when there is a dependency between static fields, it is better to use a static initializer :

```
class Foo
{
    public static string b;
    public static string a;

    static Foo()
    {
        a = "abc";
        b = a + "def";
    }
}
```

That way, you explicitly express your concern about the initialization order; or dependency for that matter (even if the compiler won't help if you accidentally swap the initialization statements.) The above will have the expected values stored in a and b (respectively "abc" and "abcdef").

However, things might get twisty (and implementation specific) for the initialization of static fields defined in multiple classes. The section [10.4.5.1 Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28VS.71%29.aspx) of the language specification talks about it some more.

Answer (score 2):

It will show allways "abcdef", because initialization goes top down in source, today just like before.

All static members will be initialized upon loading of the classtype holding them.

Comment: Which in turn means that if a maintenance programmer swaps those two lines, so that b = a + "def" comes first, b will then get initialised to "def", because a was null when b got initialised.  I.e. by doing something like this, you take a dependency on the order of declaration.